# error access violation writing location 0x00229C20. when trying to input a string in console

Tags: c++

i am trying to input a string in my code in c++ and when i run i always get the following error: Exception thrown at 0x0F5023F5 (msvcp140d.dll) in assignment-1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00229C20. i will post my code below if anyone could help me that would be great.Please note that i already know that its a problem with me  trying to access the memory location on which you dont have access to, i just dont know how to fix it.

```
HEADER FILE:
#ifndef item_H
#define item_h

class item
{
private:
    //attributes
    int itemID;
    char itemName[20];
    float itemcost;
    float itemprice;
    //utility function
    float calcPrice();

public:
    //constructor
    item(int = 000, char[] = "itemUnknown", float = 0,float = 0);
    //destructor
    ~item();
    //set functions
    void setAll(int, char[], float, float);
    void setID(int);
    void setName(char[]);
    void setCost(float);
    //get function
    int getID();
    float getcost();
    float getprice();
    void getname();
    //print function
    void print();
};
#endif

CPP:

#include "Dariush.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
//constructor will set attributes
item::item(int ID, char n[] , float c,float p)
{


        setID(ID);
        setName(n);
        setCost(c);
        setAll(ID, n, c, p);

}
//destructor will print destroing two objects
item::~item()
{
    cout << "destroing two objects : " << " " << itemName << " "
        << " & " << itemName << endl;
}
//set functions :
void item::setID(int ID)
{
    cout << "please enter the item's ID  :  " << endl;
    cin >> ID;

}
void item::setName(char n[])
{
    cout << "please enter the item's name" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(n, 20);


}
void item::setCost(float c)
{
    cout << "please enter the item's cost : " << endl;
    cin >> c;
}
void item::setAll(int ID, char n[], float c, float p)
{
    itemID = (ID > 0 && ID < 999) ? ID : 0;
    strcpy_s(itemName, n);
    itemcost = (c > 0) ? c : 0;
    calcPrice();

}
//get functions : 
int item::getID()
{
    return itemID;
}
float item::getcost()
{
    return itemcost;
}
float item::getprice()
{
    return itemprice;
}
void item::getname()
{
    cout << itemName << endl;
}
//print function :
void item::print()
{
    cout << "ID : " << itemID << endl
        << "Name : " << itemName << endl
        << "cost : " << itemcost << endl
        << "price : " << itemprice << endl;
}
// utility function for price callculation : 
float item::calcPrice()
{
    if (itemcost < 1000)
    {
        itemprice = itemcost + (itemcost*0.1);
    }
    else
        itemprice = itemcost + (itemcost*0.2);
    return itemprice;
}

MAIN.CPP:
#include "Dariush.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std ;
void main()
{
    item i1;
    item i2;
    i1.print();
    i2.print();
}
```

thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a closer look at these three function declarations:

```
item(int = 000, char[] = "itemUnknown", float = 0,float = 0);
void setAll(int, char[], float, float);
void setName(char[]);
```

The thing here is that the character "array" arguments you declare are not really arrays at all. Instead they are *pointers*. When declaring arguments, e.g. `char n[]` is actually translated by the compiler as `char *n`.

The constructor declaration makes the pointer point to the constant string literal `""`. And the important thing about constant string literals is that they are indeed *constant*. Trying to modify a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*. And change this literal is what you are trying to do with the `cin.getline(n, 20)` call in the `setName` function. Not only that, but you are also telling the `cin.getline` function to read more than fits in the string literal.

The simple solution is to have `setName` read into the member variable `itemName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code, but the one that is causing the access violation is:

```
void item::setName(char n[])
{
    cout << "please enter the item's name" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(n, 20); //here
}
```

You should use `cin.getline(itemName, 20);` instead.

Also, to prevent such error in the future, declare arguments as `char const n[]` instead of `char n[]` - good compiler should display a warning when you use string literals with non-const pointer as argument.